# Web Server Certificate’s private key and Certificate Authority’s private key?

Tags: certificate, private-key

What could a malicious attacker do with a Web Server Certificate’s private key?

What could a malicious attacker do with a Certificate Authority’s private key?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Create their own certificates.  This is an obvious question...

Answer (score 1):

> What could a malicious attacker do with a Web Server Certificate’s private key?

Impersonate that web server.

> What could a malicious attacker do with a Certificate Authority’s private key?

Impersonate that CA.